# Extend Payment method on onepagecheckout view and controller

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.90

I have developed own payment plugin in nopCommerce 3.90 version.

I want to call `OpcLoadStepAfterShippingMethod` method from my own plugin's controller and also want to extend `OpcPaymentMethods` viewpage.

I have already extend default `onepagecheckout` view page and controller for that from my plugin.

Please give me solution!

Comment: Can you please explain me brief. what you want exactly!